# inheriting from IOrderedDictionary

Tags: delphi, spring4d

I'm trying to inherit an interface from IOrderedDictionary and implement the inherited interface, see below:

```
uses
  Spring.Collections;

type
  IAttributeCollection = interface(IOrderedDictionary<String,String>)
  end;

  INodeContents = interface(IAttributeCollection)
    function Test: Boolean;
  end;

  TAttributeCollection = class(TInterfacedObject, IAttributeCollection)
  private
    FAttributes: IAttributeCollection;
    function GetAttributes: IAttributeCollection;
  public
    constructor Create;
    property Attributes: IAttributeCollection read GetAttributes implements
        IAttributeCollection;
  end;

  TNodeContents = class(TAttributeCollection, INodeContents)
  public
    function Test: Boolean;
  end;
```

This code does not compile, in TNodeContens the compiler misses the implementation e.g. for Spring.Collections.IDictionary.GetItem (beside some other but not all members).

This seems strange, when I define the generic interface directly in the unit the code complies just fine (see below).

```
type
  IOrderedDictionary<TKey, TValue> = interface(IInvokable)
  end;

  IAttributeCollection = interface(IOrderedDictionary<String,String>)
  end;

  INodeContents = interface(IAttributeCollection)
    function Test: Boolean;
  end;

  TAttributeCollection = class(TInterfacedObject, IAttributeCollection)
  private
    FAttributes: IAttributeCollection;
    function GetAttributes: IAttributeCollection;
  public
    constructor Create;
    property Attributes: IAttributeCollection read GetAttributes implements
        IAttributeCollection;
  end;

  TNodeContents = class(TAttributeCollection, INodeContents)
  public
    function Test: Boolean;
  end;
```

Comment: An interface defines, well the interface. It does it define any implementation. Your TAttributeCollection has to implement the entire interface. And it doesn't. Are you sure that inheritance is the best solution for your problem?

Comment: I would assume that TAttributeCollection implements the entire IAttributeCollection interface and therefore also the TNodeContents, at least it works in the second sample. My assumptions is that the problem is rather in the IOrderedDictionary of Spring4D, which has a much more complex inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You are deriving a new interface with

```
type
  IAttributeCollection = interface(IOrderedDictionary<String,String>)
  end;
```

That makes your life far more complex than you need. Use an alias instead:

```
type
  IAttributeCollection = IOrderedDictionary<String,String>;

  TAttributeCollection = class(TInterfacedObject, IAttributeCollection)
  private
    FAttributes: IAttributeCollection;
  public
    constructor Create;
    property Attributes: IAttributeCollection read FAttributes implements IAttributeCollection;
  end;

constructor TAttributeCollection.Create;
begin
  FAttributes := TCollections.CreateOrderedDictionary<String,String>;
end;
```

When you need to introduce another interface, don't derive from `IAttributeCollection`. Do it like this:

```
type
  INodeContents = interface
    ['{---GUID---}']
    function Test: Boolean;
  end;

  TNodeContents = class(TAttributeCollection, INodeContents)
  public
    function Test: Boolean;
  end;
```

You need the GUID so that you can query for `INodeContents`.

---

A different approach might be to inherit from the implementing class. That would look like this:

```
type
  IAttributeCollection = interface(IOrderedDictionary<String,String>)
  end;

  INodeContents = interface(IAttributeCollection)
    function Test: Boolean;
  end;

  TAttributeCollection = class(TOrderedDictionary<String,String>, IAttributeCollection)
  end;

  TNodeContents = class(TAttributeCollection, INodeContents)
  public
    function Test: Boolean;
  end;
```

---

However, I have to state that it doesn't feel to me as though either of these approaches is the right solution to your problem. It feels as though you are abusing inheritance and using it where it is not appropriate. I'm not sure what the right solution is though, because you asked about your solution rather than your problem.

Comment: This works for sure, but may intention is to extend the IAttributeCollection interface in the INodeContents  interface with additional methods while leaving the implementation of the IAttributeCollection to TAttributeCollection. I will update the second sample in the question to make the problem more clear.

Comment: Like I said, I think you have taken a wrong turn. Not all problems are solved by inheritance and I'm pretty certain that Spring4D is not designed with the expectation that you extend its interfaces. It would be more useful if you asked about your problem rather than your solution. Where does this all start?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with David that you are going about this the wrong way. The way you would tackle this would be to create a brand new interface with the extra functionality that you need and implement (either explicitly or by inheritance) the two interfaces.

What you assume is that the functions inherited from an ancestor that have the same name as the interface you are now implementing will also satisfy the second interface. This is not so, and indeed cannot be so. Interfaces may *coincidentally* have the same name, and there are special constructs to handle such cases.

So what you have done effectively is to say you need to define each function in the original interface twice.

Instead, just do not inherit from the original interface. you don't need to.

```
uses
  Spring.Collections;

type
  IAttributeCollection = interface(IOrderedDictionary<String,String>)
  end;

  INodeContents = interface
    function Test: Boolean;
  end;

  TAttributeCollection = class(TInterfacedObject, IAttributeCollection)
  private
    FAttributes: IAttributeCollection;
    function GetAttributes: IAttributeCollection;
  public
    constructor Create;
    property Attributes: IAttributeCollection read GetAttributes implements
        IAttributeCollection;
  end;

  TNodeContents = class(TAttributeCollection, INodeContents)
  public
    function Test: Boolean;
  end;
```

Now you just need to additionally implement the function Test, which is what you want to achieve.